# Alternative for checking the existence of a value in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a wordpress plugin but checking for the existence of a value doesn't really feel right because there's a bunch of values that I have to check:

```
$flickr_key = '';
if(!empty($ecom['ecom_options_flickr_api'])){
  $flickr_key = $ecom['ecom_options_flickr_api'];
}

$flickr_secret = '';
if(!empty($ecom['ecom_options_flickr_secret'])){
  $flickr_secret = $ecom['ecom_options_flickr_secret'];
}


$freebase_key = '';
if(!empty($ecom['ecom_options_freebase_api'])){
  $freebase_key = $ecom['ecom_options_freebase_api'];
}

$ebay_key = '';
if(!empty($ecom['ecom_options_ebay_api'])){
  $ebay_key = $ecom['ecom_options_ebay_api'];
}
```

Is there a more elegant alternative for this?

Answer (score 4):

As [Hugo Dozois](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/15555/hugo-dozois) suggested, using `isset` with the ternary operator is a good way to do this.

If you can assume that the options have not been set to `NULL` or `false` and you can change the `$ecom` variable you can use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) or the [`union`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) operator.

```
// Merge with your default values here.
$ecom += array('ecom_options_flickr_api'    => '',
               'ecom_options_flickr_secret' => '',
               'ecom_options_freebase_api'  => '',
               'ecom_options_ebay_api'      => '');

// Set the variables.
$flickr_key    = $ecom['ecom_options_flickr_api'];              
$flickr_secret = $ecom['ecom_options_flickr_secret'];
$freebase_key  = $ecom['ecom_options_freebase_api'];
$ebay_key      = $ecom['ecom_options_ebay_api'];
```

If they could be NULL or false you could set them using a short ternary as Hugo Dozois mentioned.  The indexes will now be set thanks to the `union` so you won't get Notices for undefined indexes.

### Other Suggestions

- I think your structure would be better represented as a multidimensional array:

  $ecom['options'] = array('flickr_api'    => '',
                           'flickr_secret' => 'etc.');
- Often intermediary variables such as `$flickr_secret` etc. are a bad idea IMO.  I prefer to use `$ecom['options']['flickr_secret']` in my code.  I find aliases normally just confuse the code.

Answer (score 1):

**Using ternary operators to removed un-necessary lines**

Well you could use the [function isset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) with the use of [ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) in order to make the code more concise.

I would do the following :

```
$flickr_key = isset($ecom['ecom_options_flickr_api']) ? $ecom['ecom_options_flickr_api'] : '' ;
$flickr_secret = isset($ecom['ecom_options_flickr_secret']) ? $ecom['ecom_options_flickr_secret']; '';
$freebase_key = isset($ecom['ecom_options_freebase_api']) ? $ecom['ecom_options_freebase_api'] : '';
$ebay_key = isset($ecom['ecom_options_ebay_api']) ? $ecom['ecom_options_ebay_api'] : '';
```

---

**Reducing the code :**

Well that is still ugly so you could make a function of it to reduce repetition of the array keys and to have something easier to read.

```
//You pass the reference of the supposed key
//Since you passe the reference, there will be no notice.
function assign(& $value $default = null){ 
    return isset($value) ? $value : $default;
}
// then use like
$flicker_key = assign($ecom['ecom_options_flickr_api'], '');
```

For more information see the [following Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836515/what-is-the-php-shorthand-for-print-var-if-var-exist/5836648#5836648).

Comment: the second method is nice but I'm still getting notices that the index doesn't exists when I do it.

Comment: @leyasu What version of php are you using? And what do you mean by motices? I've been able to run it just fine on my localhost!

Comment: I'm using PHP version 5.4.9. I'm getting this: `Notice: Undefined index: ecom_options_flickr_api`

Comment: Using ternary operator with array will copy the full array before executing the statement so with a large array it will be slow. With simply ternary operator this code wil give you E_NOTICE if the index doesn't exists no matter what PHP version is it.

Comment: @PeterKiss Alright I've removed the second part, since it was throwing a notice, and that's not clean. Thank you for the feedback